# How to evaluate: $\int_{-500}^{500}\dfrac{0.5-0.5x^2}{x^2+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, definite-integrals

So I was bored, and decided to start evaluating some integrals for fun. After a while, I came up with this:$$\int_{-500}^{500}\dfrac{0.5-0.5x^2}{x^2+1}dx$$which I thought that I might be able to evaluate. Here is my attempt at doing so:$$\begin{align}\int_{-500}^{500}\dfrac{0.5-0.5x^2}{x^2+1}dx=&\int_{-500}^{500}\dfrac{-0.5(x^2-1)}{x^2+1}dx\\=&-0.5\int_{-500}^{500}\dfrac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}dx\\\implies&-0.5\int_{-500}^{500}\dfrac{x^2+1-2}{x^2+1}dx\\\implies&-0.5\int_{-500}^{500}dx+\int_{-500}^{500}\dfrac{dx}{x^2+1}\\\implies&-500+\int_{-500}^{500}\dfrac{dx}{(x+i)(x-i)}\end{align}$$Now, using partial fractions, we get that our integral is equal to$$\begin{align}-500+\dfrac12\left(\int_{-500}^{500}\dfrac{dx}{x-i}-\int_{-500}^{500}\dfrac{dx}{x+i}\right)=&-500+\dfrac12\left(\left[\ln(x-i)\right]_{-500}^{+500}+\left[\ln(x+i)\right]_{-500}^{+500}\right)\\=&\dfrac12\left(\ln\left(\dfrac{62501500001}{62500500001}\right)\right)-500\\\approx&-499.9999840002559957\end{align}$$Note that we are using $i=\sqrt{-1}$ to get $x^2+1$ decomposed to$$(x+i)(x-i)=x^2\require{cancel}\cancel{+ix-ix}+1=x^2+1$$to do partial fraction decomposition here.

---

#### My question

---

Did I evaluate the integral correctly, or what could I do to evaluate the area correctly?

---

##### Mistakes I might have made

---

1. Partial fraction decomposition
2. Final calculation of the area

Comment: Ignore this remark if you did this on purpose but couldn't you have just gone with $\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}=\tan^{-1}(x)$?

Comment: @d0uble_a_b4ttery That would actually be my fault, since I actually forgot about that identity.

Comment: Another simplification - since your integrand is even, you may just integrate over $(0,500)$ and double the result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I did accidently evaluate the integral incorrectly. From this comment:

> Ignore this remark if you did this on purpose but couldn't you have just gone with $\int\frac1{1+x^2}=\tan^{-1}(x)$?

---

---

Step we are doing this from:$$-0.5\int_{-500}^{+500}\dfrac{x^2+1-2}{x^2+1}dx\implies-0.5\int_{-500}^{+500}dx+\int_{-500}^{+500}\dfrac{dx}{x^2+1}$$

---

---

So we have now$$\begin{align}-0.5\int_{-500}^{+500}dx+\int_{-500}^{+500}\dfrac{dx}{x^2+1}&=-500+\left[\arctan(x)\right]_{-500}^{+500}\\&=-500+\arctan(500)-\arctan(-500)\\&\approx-500+3.13759265892\\I=\int_{-500}^{+500}\dfrac{0.5-0.5x^2}{x^2+1}dx&\approx-496.86240734108\end{align}$$Meaning that my original approximation of $I\approx-499.9999840002559957$ is only off by approximately $0.631477973\%$, so it doesn't seem to be too bad using partial fraction decomposition to integrate this, although there are definitely integrals where this is more useful.